# Sum of the all the numbers between a and b

Tags: c, math, sum, constants

I need to create a program that gives the sum of the all the numbers between the constants of `a` and `b` given by the user.  `b` needs to be greater than `a`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int index, begno, endno, sum = 0;
    printf("Program for sum of all numbers in the given range\n");

    printf("Enter Beg. No.: ");
    scanf("%d", &begno);
    printf("Enter End. No.: ");
    scanf("%d", &endno);
    index = begno;

    for(; index <= endno; index ++)
        sum = sum + index;

    printf("The sum of even numbers between %d and %d is: %d", begno, endno, sum);
}
```

Comment: Wow. So you haven't even tried to do the actual "summing" work?

Comment: You might want to actually include some code that (a) compiles and (b) actually attempts to compute the sum of values you're interested in.   Then people will be more willing to help.   Otherwise, it just looks like you're trying to get someone else to do work you haven't bothered to do.

Comment: Do *not* read the inputs with scanf.  Take them as command line arguments.

Comment: Also, don't use a `for` loop to compute the sum. Instead, ask yourself: WWGD ([what would Gauss do](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.02.06/jo1.html))?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the sum of _all_ numbers or the sum of _all even_ numbers?

Comment: Someone has changed the question to hold the answer rather than answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code given looks OK, but if you want the sum without including the last number, as is generally the case you should change the for loop like this

```
for(; index < endno; index ++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by implementing a loop to compute:
$$\sum_{n=a}^{b}
n$$